# Increased release APK size after upgrading to Android studio 2.1

Tags: android-studio

APK size of APP increases from 6.9 MB to 19.9 MB.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Instant Run will make your app larger, but that doesn't apply to "release" builds. Open the APK file (like any other ZIP archive) and compare it with your older APK.

Comment: so,what is solution for that

Comment: are you sure you've not added any other dependencies after migrating to AS 2.1?

Comment: yes i have added PayPal

Comment: @PradeepGupta this isn't an issue with Android Studio.

Comment: remove paypal temporarily and see what you get

Comment: @AndroidMechanic after removing paypal i get size 6.9 MB

Comment: but i have to used PayPal

Comment: then you have to accept the additional size. to trim it down use appropriate proguard rules such that it does not break your paypal functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because of in older `apk` you have used jar files as `comile files` and in new apk you have changed to `compile` with path. Thats why its size was increased. specifically check for `Paypal`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on our conversation on the question comments. The increased size is because of an added paypal dependency and not because of upgrading the AS 2.1.

Removing the dependency brought back your apk to the previous size. Hence the size increase is because of the added paypal dependency.

**To trim it down use appropriate proguard rules such that it does not break your paypal functionality or check if there is a minimal variant available to add as depenedncy (I've not used it so cannot confirm if a minimal one exists or not)**